Varshamov bound is stronger than Gilbert bound
In the class of Error-correcting Code, the professor showed us $2$ results:
Theorem 1(Gilbert)
$$ B_q(n,d)\geqslant \frac{q^n}{V_q(n,d-1)}$$
where $V_q(n,d-1)$ denotes the cardinality of the ball $B_{d-1}(0)$, i.e:
$$ V_q(n,d-1)=\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} \binom{n}{i}(q-1)^i$$
Theorem 2(Varshamov)
$$ B_q(n,d)\geqslant q^{n-\lceil \log_q(1+V_q(n-1,d-2))\rceil}$$
The professor also remarked that:
(1) Varshamov bound is slightly stronger than the Gilbert bound.
(2) These $2$ bounds are asymptotically the same.
My question is:
(1) By saying that Varshamov bound is slightly stronger than the Gilbert bound, does he mean Varshamov bound implies the Gilbert bound in general, or just an unrigid remark? If so, how can we prove this or disprove this?
(2) What's the exact meaning by saying that these $2$ bounds are asymptotically the same?
Thanks in advance!

For both your questions, first look at the following graph of some classic coding theory bounds, from page 83 of the Guruswami-Rudra-Sudan textbook. (GV is the Gilbert-Varshamov). Understanding bounds visually as lines on a graph might help with the answers to this question.


He doesn't mean strength in terms of logical implication, he means that one bound gives a better idea of how good codes can be than the other bound. (Like, in the sense that $5 < x$ is a better lower bound on $x$ than $-2 < x$, when both are true).

Remember that the rate $R = \frac{k}{n}$ and the relative minimum distance $\delta = \frac{d}{n}$ for an $[n,k,d]_q$ code. So while the Gilbert and Varshamov bounds might be different for small $n$, they approach the same line as $n \rightarrow \infty$.


